# Export pandas.io.excel object into excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have reponse object that contain excel file, which i am decoding like this

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
```

Now i want to export this into a .xlsx file.
This object had pandas.io.excel._base.Excelfile type.
Is there any way to export this.
I have tried .to_excel but that didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExcelFile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.html)'s purpose is to **read and parse** excel files into pandas objects.

If your object is already an excel file, why pass it to `ExcelFile` at all?

Directly save the `response.content` to a file:

```
with open('outfile.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

If you want to save the individual sheets, you can indeed use pandas:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))

for name in xl.sheet_names:
    xl.parse(name).to_csv(f'{name}.xlsx')
```